# removing G(j,i) entries

Tags: arrays, data-structures, graph

I am solving a graph problem . Its an undirected graph . Say there are 4 vertices (1,2,3,4) and vertices are linked as below.

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,1
3,1
4,1
```

G(i,j) and G(j,i) both exist as above (G- graph, i - source vertex, j-destincation vertex). Now, i need to remove all G(j,i) from it. which could be the effecient way.

I tried inserting all i vertex into one array and j vertex into another array . Something like

```
a[0] = 1 and b[0] = 2
a[1] = 1 and b[1] = 3
so on..
```

But its being difficult for me to remove G(j,i) entries. I have 3 questions.

1. is there any efficient algoirthm which removes duplicates (here duplicates i say, bcoz G(i,j) = G(j,i).
2. Instead of using array, is there any data structure which can perform this operation easier.
3. which datastructure is commonly used for Graph problems.

Comment: i use linked list for all graph problems, it works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph is typically represented either in an adjacency matrix form, or an adjacency list.

Let n = the # of nodes, and m = # of edges, and the ID of the nodes are integers labeled from 0 - (n-1)

In an adjacency matrix, you essentially have a 2D array of size n x n. The value at index `[i][j]`  is 0 if there is no edge between nodes `i` and `j`, and non-zero otherwise. If your graph is unweighted, the matrix is typically binary (0 for no edge, 1 for edge), and you can use a matrix of boolean values to save on space instead. If your graph is undirected, observe that the matrix will be symmetric, since an edge at `[i][j]` indicates an edge at `[j][i]`.

However, if space efficiency is a concern and your graph is sparse in terms of edges, there will be a lot of wasted space as the data structure will take O(n^2) regardless of the # of edges.

The alternative is an adjacency list, which takes O(n + m) space. Here we can have a 1D array, where each element of an array is a container (say a linked list or a hash set). The `i`th container of the array holds the ID of nodes that are connected to the `ith` node.

To address the issue of removing duplicates in that "edgelist" format you have, it seems you want an undirected graph, meaning an edge from `i` to `j` implies an edge from `j` to `i`. In an adjacency matrix, this can be done simply by setting `[i][j] = [j][i] = true`. In an adjacency list, using a `set` container will be best as a `set` guarentees no duplicate edges. Thus, when you see an edge from `i` to `j` in your edgelist, you simply index into the `i`th cell and add in `j`, and index into the `j`th cell and add in `i`. Later on when you see `j` to `i`, you will do the same, but adding the duplicate values into the hash set will do nothing.

Comment: Thats a great help . I will try using set.